# Field Compatibility in Experience Editor

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

I have a Custom Time field that inherits the the IContentField of namespace Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor. I am trying to edit this field in Experience Editor using Edit Frame. But the value edited in Experience Editor Mode is not getting Populated or updated in the Field.
Is there any compatibility issue with the field? How can i make it editable in Experience editor.